# I think this would be called an inline text align: center but cannot get it to work in this code

Tags: html

I want to have the "Sizes" to align center and have tried everything, can someone show me what and where to insert to make this happen.

thanks

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<center>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NX728BPDLS4QC">
<table align=“center”>

<tr><td style="color: white”><input type="hidden" name="on0"   value="Sizes">Sizes</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="6 x 6">6 x 6 $100.00 USD</option>
    <option value="12 x 12">12 x 12 $200.00 USD</option>
    <option value="24 x 24">24 x 24 $400.00 USD</option>
    <option value="48 x 48">48 x 48 $800.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image"  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your code in this part need edit:

```
<td style="color: white”>
```

must be like this:

```
<td style="color: white">
```

change your codes with this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<center>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NX728BPDLS4QC">
<div class="sell">
<table align=“center”>
<tr>
    <td style="color: white">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0"   value="Sizes">Sizes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="os0">
    <option value="6 x 6">6 x 6 $100.00 USD</option>
    <option value="12 x 12">12 x 12 $200.00 USD</option>
    <option value="24 x 24">24 x 24 $400.00 USD</option>
    <option value="48 x 48">48 x 48 $800.00 USD</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image"  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</center>
</form>
```

then try this code on your stylesheet file:

```
.sell{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to point out that you have a fancy quote in your style declaration, that could cause problems if not addressed :)

As for your question, adding

```
text-align: center;
```

to your style declaration will center your text

so your new td should look like this:

```
<tr><td style="color: white; text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" name="on0"   value="Sizes">Sizes</td></tr>
```